# NgTagInput- It's not possible to select the Second tag immediately after the First tag is added?

Tags: javascript

NgTagInput- It's not possible to select the Second tag immediately after the First tag is added? 
We have to focus it outside & again focus inside to show the suggestion box

Answer (score 0):

```
   1) In tagsInput.directive('tagsInput', ...
    we have to add code for click event
     scope.eventHandlers = {
                 click: function ($event) {
                            events.trigger('input-click', $event);
                        },
   2) Then in tagsInput.directive('autoComplete',...
    tagsInputConfig.load('autoComplete', $scope, $attrs, {
    loadOnClick: [Boolean, false],

   3) Then in tagsInput
                    .on('tag-added tag-removed invalid-tag input-blur', function() {
                        suggestionList.reset();
                    })
                   .on('input-click', function () {
                        var value = tagsInput.getCurrentTagText();
                        if (options.loadOnClick) {
                            suggestionList.load(value, tagsInput.getTags());
                        }
                    })
                   .on('tag-clicked', function () {
                         event.preventDefault();
                         event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    })

   4) Then in Html template 
    tagsInput.run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
       ng-click=\"eventHandlers.input.click($event)\" 
       ng-blur=\"eventHandlers.input.blur($event)\"

   5) then in your HTML code we can loadOnClick set it to true
```